# Anko - Setting row and column value for an element in gridLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

How do I set column and row value for an element in gridLayout in Anko?

I tried several versions, but this does not compile:

```
   return UI {
        gridLayout() {
            columnCount = 2
            rowCount = 3
            button("1x1") {

            }.lparams() { column = 1; row = 1 }
        }
    }.view
```

When I put it like this (as a function), or as properties inside curly brackets, it says it cannot reference `column` or `row`. When I provide them as arguments to lparams, it says `none of the following functions can be called with arguments supplied`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) documentation:

> Children occupy one or more contiguous cells, as defined by their
>   `rowSpec` and `columnSpec` layout parameters. Each spec defines the set of
>   rows or columns that are to be occupied; and how children should be
>   aligned within the resulting group of cells.

You can use `rowSpec` and `columnSpec` like so:

```
return UI {
    gridLayout() {
        columnCount = 2
        rowCount = 3
        button("1x1") {

        }.lparams {
            rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(1)
            columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(1)
        }
    }
}.view
```